# Delaying Gameplay before GameOver screen

Tags: ios

I use Objective C for project.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(RED.frame, Ground.frame)) {    
    //[self GameOver];
    [REDmove invalidate];
    [REDtime invalidate];
  [self performselector:@selector(GameOver) withObject:self afterDelay:1.5 ];
}
```

But Xcode gives issue saying "No visible @interface for 'MainiPhone' declares the selector 'performselector:withObject:afterDelay:"

I've use this selector in a previous app but now it doesn't work. Why not? What's Xcode want?

This code for [self performselector:@selector , does even pop up on screen anymore after I type it. Instead of the code I want there is an option for...

```
 [self performSelector:(nonnull SEL) withObject:(nullable id) afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)]
```

Don't know what the above is?

Comment: That's exactly the method you want.  It's saying that the selector must not be `nil`, but the object can be `nil`.  Apple added `nonnull` and `nullable` annotations to a large part of the SDK in Xcode 7, for better interaction with Swift.

Comment: Suggestion - use `dispatch_after` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a capital "S" in `performSelector`, thus:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(GameOver) withObject:self afterDelay:1.5];
```

Comment: That makes not difference, I checked.

Comment: Is `MainiPhone` a protocol that does not extend the `NSObject` protocol?  If it extends `NSObject`, that should work.

Comment: MainiPhone is the name of my class.

Comment: In that case, it should extend `NSObject` eventually.  So it should indeed have that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't be found if you're sure that you included a capital "S", since it is defined on `NSObject`.

Comment: Eric Galluzzo in the comment above is correct. Apple changed this selector in Xcode 7. For Xcode 7 just use the final selector I mentioned at the end of my question, if you'll ever need it in Xcode 7. Sorry I didn't notice, you're the same person above. Well thanks for your help.